# Pulling asp:FileUpload upload data through AJAX. Is it possible?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, file-upload

I have a task to make a feature that uploads images more modern and up to date.

Currently, the asp:FileUpload option sits within a form and both the form and asp:FileUpload run at the server.

This is a simplified version of my code:

```
<form id="form1" action="/handle.aspx" runat="server" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <asp:FileUpload runat="server" name="PhotoUpload" ID="PhotoUpload" />
    <label>Please upload an image</label>
</form>


    $('#form1').submit(function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: $('#form1').serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                alert('This form was successful');
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

I'm pretty sure my ajax call works correctly because the form submits in the behind code.  My problem is when I try to pull the values from the asp:FileUpload, it is always null in the behind code.

In the back, I try and gather the image file this way but it always comes back as null:

```
HttpPostedFile holder = PhotoUpload.PostedFile;
```

Now for my question:

Is it possible for my ajax call to submit the asp:FileUpload information to the server even though the button is being run at the server? Should I go about it a different way?

I'm not sure if there are some discrepancies with submitting information that is run at server.

Please let me know what you think.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code I used that worked for me:

```
    $('#form').submit(function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: new FormData(this),
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (data) { $('target').html(data); },
            error: function (error) { console.log(error); }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

processData must be set to false, contentType is false in my code because my form contains enctype="multipart/form-data" which is also nessesary to submit the file through an AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

Ok well after hours of research I found a great way to do it through AJAX.

That is using the FormData to pass the file uploaded.

Here is documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

So uhh....thanks for the views :)

Comment: it would be better to provide complete solution how you made it work

Comment: Added another comment